# About addStaticObservation function?

Tags: slam, navigation, mapping, costmap-2d, layered-costmap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi ROS developers,

I can't find any documentation or comments concerning the function

**void costmap_2d::ObstacleLayer::addStaticObservation  (   costmap_2d::Observation &   obs,
bool   marking,
bool   clearing
)**

Can you tell me what's the role of this function ? is it to add a new obstacle to the costmap's obstacle layer ? and how and when can I use it ?

Waiting for your help.

Regards.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/205957/about-addstaticobservation-function-?/) by [assil](https://answers.ros.org/users/10216/assil/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2015-03-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This function primarily exists for testing purposes. For non-testing purposes, I would use the standard subscribers to add observations to your costmap.

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2015-03-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [assil](https://answers.ros.org/users/10216/assil/) on 2015-03-29**:
Hi David, Thank you for your answer .
Can you give me more details about the standard subscribers please ? I'm newbe in ROS and I need Help.

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2015-03-30**:
Rather than reading the source, I recommend you start here: http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials